# Can I access multiple azure accounts with azure-cli from the same machine at same time?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

We actually have multiple azure accounts (for some valid reason) and I want to be able to run azure-cli commands for different accounts at the same time from the same machine.

The problem with that is, once I login to one azure account with `azure login`, token will be stored in ~/.azure directory so I am not sure if I can login into another account exactly at the same time on that machine.

Is there any way to tell azure-cli not to store token in local profile so that I can use azure-cli to connect to multiple accounts at the same time from same machine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using a windows or mac machine then the tokens are stored in Windows token manager or OSx key chain respectively. Only on Linux systems the tokens are stored in ~/.azure/azureProfile.json

However, you should still be able to login with multiple accounts on Win/Mac or Linux machines.

azure account set "subscription-name" will set the subscription as your default subscription and all the commands that you execute will run against that subscription.

Every command has a -s or --subscription switch where you can explicitly specify the subscription id. Even if the subscription belongs to a different account, it should still work if you have authenticated with that account.

For Linux system, I would suggest to create multiple user accounts and then run the CLI from those accounts. I think there could be a race condition when two commands from different accounts try to access ~/.azure/azureProfile.json.

Comment: Tracking the further discussion in https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2198 for interested.

Answer (score 8):

The latest update is that the environment variable **AZURE_CONFIG_DIR** has been introduced and that can be set differently for each environment before `az login` is called.

> export AZURE_CONFIG_DIR=/tmp1
>
> az login

and on other window

> export AZURE_CONFIG_DIR=/tmp2
>
> az login

Reference: [configure the AZURE_CONFIG_DIR for fixing concurrency issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8314)

Answer (score 2):

For ***Windows***, here are steps

1. Go to env variables and add `AZURE_CONFIG_DIR` with the value of new config folder (e.x. `C:\Users\YourUser\.azure-personal`)
2. restart your cli, then run this `az login --use-device-code`
3. use the code given on step 2 and use it with whatever browser to login to new azure account

Now, one of your accounts config is in default azure folder config (`C:\Users\YourUser\.azure`) and new one lives in the place you specified on step 1.

if you wanna **switch between them**, you need to flip that env variable to point to whatever config you want